# Table in a table with C# in LINQPad 4

Tags: c#, linqpad

Like you see in my picture I have a table in a table, how can I solve this problem?

[image: Picture]

I did that with C# statements.

```
var testGR = (from doc in DocumentTypes select new { doc.PIMID, documentTypeLabel = from docLabel in doc.DocumentTypeLabels select new {docLabel.Name}}); testGR.Dump();
```

How can I change my code to get the result like in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this:

```
var testGR = 
  from doc in DocumentTypes 
  select new 
  {
    doc.PIMID,
    documentTypeLabel = doc.DocumentTypeLabels.FirstOrDefault (l => l.Name)
  };

testGR.Dump();
```